# Wörter, die das Gegenteil bedeuten

Tags: word-usage, meaning, compound

Sprache dient der präzisen Wissensübertragung. Doch in der deutschen Sprache gibt es Wörter, die für sich betrachtet das Gegenteil dessen bedeuten, wofür sie stehen. Trotzdem ist für die Allgemeinheit die Bedeutung bekannt. Gemeint sind Wörter wie *Hustensaft* oder *Kopfschmerztablette*. Natürlich soll Hustensaft keinen Husten verursachen und Kopfschmerztabletten keinen Kopfschmerz. Eigentlich müssten sie Antihustensaft und Antikopfschmerztabletten genannt werden.

Gibt es in der deutschen Sprache noch mehr solcher Wörter?

Gibt es eine Bezeichnung für die Art von Wörtern?

Die letzte Frage ist ein wenig weiter gefasst und eventuell gar nicht zu beantworten. Wie ist es möglich, dass solche Wörter in einer Sprache überhaupt entstehen, da sie eben nicht einen Sachverhalt genau beschreiben, sondern sogar das genaue Gegenteil?

Comment: Kopfschmerztabletten sind Tabletten die man einnimmt wenn man Kopfschmerzen hat. Gibt es überhaupt ein Medikament, bei dem die Benennung anders rum ist? Ein Wintermantel hilft auch gegen die Kälte des Winters aber wird eben im Winter getragen. Die Behauptung, es müsse eigentlich anders herum lauten, halte ich für falsch.

Comment: Das "Anti-"Medikament: Antibiotikum.

Comment: Seit wann spielen Meinungen eine Rolle @user unknown?

Comment: Doris: People think it means the opposite of what it means.
Felix: Do they?
Doris: But it doesn't.
Felix: No, words rarely do.
Doris: Do what?
Felix: Mean the opposite of what they mean.

Comment: Hmm - (natürliche) Sprache dient m.E. nur im Ausnahmefall der „_präzisen_“ Wissensübertragung. Im Regelfall übermittelt sie nur ungenaue, interpretationsbedürftige Informationen. Die Bedeutung der verwendeten Zeichen kann sich außerdem im Zeitverlauf radikal ändern. Um so präziser eine Sprache wird, um so unverständlicher wird sie für die Allgemeinheit. D.h. Alltagssprache ist strukturell vage. Und gerade Nomenkomposita sind im besonderen Maße ungenau, da das Verhältnis der beteiligten Nomen von Fall zu Fall bestimmt werden muss.

Comment: Wieso gibt es denn hier 5 Downvotes. Die Frage mag zwar auf einem Irrtum beruhen (siehe meine Antwort), ist aber anständig ausgeführt und es haben sich bestimmt schon viele Leute (speziell Lerner) das gleiche gefragt. Bloß weil man eine Frage dumm findet ist das kein Grund sie runterzuvoten. Und so dumm ist sie garnicht. Da gibt es hier ganz andere Kaliber. Also bitte Leute, macht die Downvotes weg oder erklärt euch.

Comment: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komposition_%28Grammatik%29#Typisierung_von_Nomina_nach_semantischen_Mustern

Comment: @userunknown: Die "Anti-Baby-Pille", die man nach dem Muster der "Kopfschmerztabletten" etc. "Baby-Pille" nennen müsste.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Das Grundproblem mit der Frage ist, dass deine Interpretation von

> Kopfschmerztablette

eben genau das ist... eine Interpretation von vielen möglichen.
Die Teile in zusammengesetzten Wörtern können in ganz unterschiedlichen Beziehungen stehen.

> Hundedecke (Decke für Hunde)       –  Wolldecke (Decke aus Wolle)
>   Schlüsselloch (Loch für Schlüssel) – Erdloch (Loch in der Erde)
>   Regenschirm (Schirm gegen Regen)    – Bildschirm (Schirm für Bild)
>   Eisskulptur (Skulptur aus Eis)      – Eiskratzer (Kratzer für/gegen Eis)

Wenn keine Fugenelemente vorhanden sind, bleibt einem nur der gesunde Menschenverstand oder der Kontext.
Das Wort

> Kopfschmerztablette

lässt objektiv nur den Schluss zu, dass es eine Tablette ist, die mit Kopfschmerzen zu tun hat. Das trifft auf alle folgenden Deutungen zu

> Tablette für Kopfschmerzen
>   Tablette gegen Kopfschmerzen
>   Tablette aus Kopfschmerzen
>   Tablette mit Kopfschmerzen

Manche machen mehr Sinn als andere und die sinnvollste Bedeutung wird sich wohl schnell durchsetzen.

Daher gibt es keine besondere Bezeichnung, weil diese Wörter eben genau nix Besonderes sind.

Ich kann schließlich auch sagen "Hundedecke" ist solch ein Wort, das sein Gegenteil heißt, da es theoretisch auch "Decke gegen Hunde" heißen könnte.

Comment: Danke fürs ernsthafte Auseinandersetzen mit der Frage und nicht fürs von oben herab vorverurteilen. Daher akzeptiert.

Comment: Papa, warum heißt ein Schweinsschnitzel »Schweinsschnitzel«? - Weil es aus dem Fleisch eines Schweines ist. - Und ein Putenschnitzel? - Das ist aus dem Fleisch einer Pute. - Und Kalbsschnitzel? - Na, rate mal. - Aus dem Fleisch eines Kalbes? - Ja, sehr gut! Du hat's verstanden. - Du Papa? - Ja? - Ich mag mein Kinderschnitzel nicht mehr.

Comment: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komposition_%28Grammatik%29#Typisierung_von_Nomina_nach_semantischen_Mustern

Answer (score 8):

Nur, weil etwas einen Namensbestandteil hat, kann man nicht drauf schliessen, wie dieser Namensbestandteil gemeint ist. Das ergibt sich aus dem Kontext.

Siehe auch Babyöl (für Babys) und Olivenöl (aus Oliven).

Das ist in anderen Sprachen genauso (Englisch: baby oil and olive oil).

Comment: Hundekuchen sind nicht aus Hund, Schokokekse  aber aus (mit) Schokolade gemacht. Und Zitronenfalter falten keine Zitronen.

Comment: Mir fällt es schwer hier eine Antwort auf die Frage(n) zu erkennen. Daher down vote.

Comment: @solid Was erwartest Du in einer Antwort, was hier fehlt? Du hast nach mehr Beispielen gefragt, und ich habe welche gebracht. Ich habe Dich auf Deinen Denkfehler, den Kontext ausser Acht zu lassen, hingeweisen. Was brauchst Du noch?

Answer (score 1):

Hustensaft ist kein Saft, der Husten verursacht - darauf käme wohl keiner, sondern Saft gegen den Husten oder Saft, der gut ist bei Husten. "Wörter, die das Gegenteil bedeuten" zeigt ein falsches Verständnis der Substantiv-Kompositionen.