# Strange little problem with being in "Gefahr"

Tags: word-usage, etymology, history

There are a lot of "irregular" and misleading "zusammengesetzte Nomen" in German. And most of them are quite famous. For example, "Olivenöl" is oil made out of olives. "Sonnenblumenöl" is made from sunflowers. What is "Babyöl" made of? I do know that there is probably hundreds of these, and no one really cares about it, but there is one peculiar case that will not let go of me.

It's words that warn from danger:

- Erstickungsgefahr: you might suffocate.
- Verbrennungsgefahr: you might get burned
- Absturzgefahr: you might fall down
- Lebensgefahr: you might... live?

Of course it means "your life is in danger", but to me (and I **am** german) the word literally means "danger of living" and it also contradicts every single other ...Gefahr that I can think of. And this has bothered me for **years** now.

> So here's my question: does anyone by chance know the origin of this
>   word and why it stands out so much?

I would also appreciate some comments telling me if it also feels strange to you.

Comment: Es handelt sich eben um *Gefahr für Leib und Leben* statt *Gefahr, XXX zu erleiden*. Es wird eine Qualität beschrieben, nicht die Sache, die passieren könnte. Ich glaube, es ist auch das einzige Wort der Gruppe *Gefahr* mit eigenem Adjektiv, *lebensgefährlich*. Zusammengesetzte Substantive sind immer Abkürzungen, die einen Aspekt hervorheben - und das muss nicht immer derselbe Typ Aspekt sein. Dass es in der Gefahr-Gruppe kein weiteres Beispiel gibt liegt vielleicht eher daran, dass weitere Qualitätseinstufungen nicht nötig sind und im Allgemeinen eine konkrete Bedrohung vorliegt.

Comment: Siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20147/w%c3%b6rter-die-das-gegenteil-bedeuten/

Comment: Du kennst selbst Beispiele, die Deine These widerlegen, alle Substantivverbindungen gehorchten der gleichen Präposition, zählst dann eine Gruppe auf, die insgesamt wieder eine anderes Verhältnis prägt als die erste Gruppe. Ich darf ergänzen Hustensaft und Augentropfen. Oder Holztisch, Verhandlungstisch, Küchentisch, Billardtisch, Beistelltisch, Mittagstisch, Stammtisch, Nachtisch. Dein Besipiel sticht gar nicht heraus, das ist einfach Einbildung. Der Fehler ist, aus einer partiellen Regelmäßigkeit auf eine Regel zu schließen.

Comment: @Chieron: "Dass es in der Gefahr-Gruppe kein weiteres Beispiel gibt" - Gesundheitsgefahr.

Comment: Bitte beim nächsten Mal beachten: Du betonst, selbst Deutscher zu sein und stellst in einem Deutsch-Forum eine Frage zu einem Aspekt der deutschen Sprache. In deinem Profil gibst du auch an, dass Deutsch eine deiner beiden Muttersprachen ist. Warum also stellst du deine Frage in einer anderen Sprache als Deutsch? Wer wird deiner Meinung nach deine Frage lesen und beantworten? Ich kann es dir sagen: Menschen, die sich für die deutsche Sprache interessieren. Also Leute, die DEUTSCH sprechen.

Comment: Fortsetzung: Dass man hier Fragen auch auf Englisch stellen kann ist nur ein Zugeständnis an jene, die Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernen und diese Fremdsprache noch schlechter als Englisch beherrschen. (Wobei viele Englisch auch nur als Fremdsprache gelernt haben und eine ganz andere Muttersprache sprechen).

Comment: Babyöl ist **für** Babies.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich bewege mich in mehreren StackExchangegruppen, und in allen ist englisch die dominante Sprache. für mich ist "German Language" nur eine weitere Gruppe, die als Thema eben die deutsche Sprache hat. Darum habe ich den Beitrag in Englisch verfasst. Ich war mir nicht bewusst, dass das in dieser Gruppe so nicht erwünscht ist, und werde zukünftig darauf achten.

Comment: @AndreasHeese Das hat mit "erwünscht" nichts zu tun, du darfst deine Frage gerne auf Deutsch oder Englisch stellen, ganz nach Lust und Laune. Ich hoffe, was Hubert sagen wollte, war, dass du u.U. auf Deutsch mehr qualifizierte Antworten von Muttersprachern (nämlich auch denen, die des Englischen nicht so mächtig sind) bekommen könntest.

Comment: @Chieron explosionsgefährlich

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Regeln für Komposita:

1. Ein Kompositum ist ein zusammengesetztes Substantiv. Dabei gibt der vordere Teil eine Spezialisierung des hinteren Teils an. Das heißt: Das Wort ohne den vorderen Teil ist ein Überbegriff des zusammengesetzten Wortes. Auf welche Weise diese Spezialisierung vollzogen wird, ergibt sich aus den Bedeutungen der beiden Teile und aus dem Kontext und wird durch keine Grammatikregel beeinflusst.

   Diese Bedeutungsdominanz des hinteren Teils ist übrigens auch der Grund, warum das grammatische Geschlecht des zusammengesetzten Wortes ausschließlich und ausnahmslos von diesem letzen Teil genommen wird.
2. Zwischen die beiden Bestandteile eines Kompositums kann noch ein Fugenlaut eingeschoben werden, wofür es eine Vielzahl von Regeln gibt, die einander häufig widersprechen und regional unterschiedlich sind. Diese Fugenlaut-Regeln sind aber nicht Gegenstand dieser Frage.
3. Der Prozess des Zusammenfügens von Substantiven zu Komposita kann rekursiv und (zumindest theoretisch) beliebig oft wiederholt werden, wodurch beliebig lange Komposita entstehen können. Das heißt, dass auch einer der beiden Bestandteile eines Kompositums selbst wieder ein Kompositum sein kann. Das trifft sowohl auf den vorderen als auch für den hinteren Teil zu.

   [image: Fußbodenschleifmaschinenverleih]

   Das längste Kompositum, das bisher in einem offiziellen Dokument verwendet wurde, besteht aus 63 Buchstaben und lautet [Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindfleischetikettierungs%C3%BCberwachungsaufgaben%C3%BCbertragungsgesetz). Aber selbst dieses Monster darf selbst wieder in Übereinstimmung mit den deutschen Grammatikregeln als Teil eines noch längeren Kompositums verwendet werden. Aus diesem Grund hat die Sprache Deutsch kein längstes Wort. Denn aus jedem Wort, dass als Kandidat in Frage kommt, kann man ein noch längeres machen.

   - **Ergänzung**, eingefügt am 9. Dezember 2016:
     Das österreichische Wort des Jahres 2016 lautet:

     > Bundespräsidentenstichwahlwiederholungsverschiebung

Beispiel **Schokoladenosterhasenfabrik**:

- Ein **Hase** ist ein Säugetier mit langen Ohren und kurzem Schwanz, das sonst in Größe und Form in etwa einer Katze ähnlich sieht.
- Ein **Osterhase** ist ein spezieller Hase, nämlich ein Fantasietier, von dem man sich erzählt, dass es zu Ostern Eier in Nester legt.
- Ein **Schokoladenosterhase** ist ein spezieller Osterhase. Das ist nämlich eine Nachbildung eines Osterhasen aus Schokolade.
- Eine **Fabrik** ist eine Anlage (häufig ein Gebäude), in der etwas hergestellt wird.
- Eine **Schokoladenosterhasenfabrik** ist eine spezielle Fabrik, nämlich eine, in der Schokoladenosterhasen hergestellt werden.

Wie man sieht, gibt es völlig unterschiedliche Arten der Spezialisierung. Einmal wird nach einem Fest eingeschränkt, ein anderes Mal nach einem Material und das dritte Mal nach einem Produkt. Die deutsche Sprache ist da völlig offen, und legt der Art der Spezialisierung keinerlei Beschränkung auf.

Daher ist es nicht verwunderlich, dass es für ein und denselben Obergebriff nicht nur verschiedene Spezialbegriffe gibt, sondern auch verschiedene Arten, wie diese Spezialisierung erfolgen kann.

Um beim Öl zu bleiben:

Die Spezialisierung kann nach der Herkunft des Öls erfolgen:

- **Erdöl:** Öl, das aus der Erde gepumpt wird.
- **Nussöl:** Öl, das aus einer Nuss gewonnen wird.
- **Erdnussöl:** Öl das aus einer Nuss gewonnen wird, die in der Erde wächst.

Sie kann aber auch nach der Anwendung, für die das Öl vorgesehen ist, erfolgen:

- **Maschinenöl:** Öl, um Maschinen zu schmieren.
- **Nähmaschinenöl:** Öl, um Maschinen zu schmieren mit denen man nähen kann.
- **Kriechöl:** Öl, das zwischen zwei eng aneinander liegende Werkstücke kriechen kann.
- **Massageöl:** Öl, das geeignet ist, bei Massagen verwendet zu werden.
- **Babyöl:** Öl, das zur Hautpflege von Kleinkindern vorgesehen ist.

Bei der **Gefahr** ist das dasselbe. Hier kann man nach der Ursache unterscheiden, oder nach dem gefährdeten Gut.

Spezialisierungen der Gefahr nach Ursache:

- Erstickungsgefahr
- Verbrennungsgefahr
- Absturzgefahr

Spezialisierungen der Gefahr nach dem gefährdeten Gut:

- Lebensgefahr
- Gesundheitsgefahr

Selbst wenn es für einen Oberbegriff und eine Spezialisierungsart nur ein einziges Kompositum gäbe (wenn es also die Gesundheitsgefahr nicht gäbe), und wenn alle Komposita, die vom selben Oberbegriff abgeleitet sind, allesamt einer einzigen anderen Spezialisierungsart angehören (wenn also alle Gefahr-Komposita mit Ausnahme der *Lebensgefahr* nach der Ursache unterscheiden würden), wäre das völlig legitim und kein Verstoß gegen irgendwelche Regeln.

---

Im übrigen erinnert mich diese Frage sehr an diesen Witz:

> Du, Papa?
>   Ja?
>   Was ist ein Rindsschnitzel?
>   Das ist ein Schnitzel, das aus einem Rind gemacht wird.
>   Und ein Schweinsschnitzel?
>   Ein Schnitzel aus einem Schwein.
>   Und ein Hühnerschnitzel?
>   Na komm, das weißt du jetzt aber schon selber.
>   Aus einem Huhn?
>   Ja! Bravo, sehr gut!
>   *(kurze Pause)*
>   Du, Papa.
>   Was denn, mein Schatz?
>   Ich mag mein Kinderschnitzel nicht mehr.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die umfangreiche und erheiternde Antwort :)

Comment: Die Erdnuss ist aber keine Nuss, sondern eine Hülsenfrucht. :)

Comment: @userunknown: Das eine schließt das andere nicht aus. Eine Nussfrucht im engeren Sinn liegt vor, wenn bei einer Frucht alle drei Schichten der Fruchtwand verholzen. Das ist bei der Erdnuss der Fall. Um eine Hülsenfrucht handelt es sich dann, wenn die Samen (Kerne) von einem einzigen Fruchtblatt umschlossen werden. Auch das ist bei der Erdnuss der Fall. Siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nussfrucht#N.C3.BCsse_im_botanischen_Sinne

Answer (score 3):

Wie du selber schon gemerkt hast, gibt es bei zusammengesetzten Nomen **keine richtigen Regeln**. Zum Glueck, denn dadurch koennen sogenannte Wortneuschoepfungen entstehen, welche unsere Sprache bereichern.

Genauso wie es das Wort Lebensgefahr gibt, gibt es auch das Wort Todesgefahr. **Beide bedeuten das selbe**. Todesgefahr ist die Gefahr vor dem Tod, Lebensgefahr ist die Gefahr fuer das Leben.

**Um deine Frage konkret zu beantworten:** Es gibt keinen Urpsrung, Irgendjemand hat sich das mal so ueberlegt und es hat sich eben durchgesetzt (klingt ja auch um einiges positiver). Arbeitsschutz schuetzt auch nicht vor der Arbeit und eine Kaffeekanne ist auch keine Kanne aus Kaffee...

*PS: Wenn du deutsch bist, wieso fragst du dann nicht auf deutsch?*

Comment: GIbt es keine Regeln oder keine richtigen Regeln? Was wären denn die falschen Regeln, die es gibt? Wieso sind die Wortneuschöpfungen keine Wortneuschöpfungen sondern werden nur so genannt? Drittens: Wenn Du weißt, dass es sich mal jemand so überlegt hat - wieso ist das dann nicht der Ursprung? Viertens: Wieso sollte eine Warnung vor Gefahren positiv klingen? Sollte man es dann nicht noch positiver Todesgelegenheit oder Sterbechance nennen?

Comment: Es gibt Regeln (wie z.B. dass das neu gebildete Word gross- und zusammengeschrieben werden muss), allerdings keine die auf irgendeine Logik eingehen. Wer sagt, dass Wortneuschoepfungen nur so genannt werden und keine sind? Keinen logischen Ursprung (nach dem, so wie ich das verstanden hatte, gefragt wurde). Tod ist ein negatives Wort, Leben ein postives, dementsprechend klingt Lebensgefahr positiver als Todesgefahr.

Comment: 1. Also es gibt Regeln, und die sind richtig, aber passen nicht zur Frage. Du schreibst es gäbe keine richtigen Regeln. - 2. Du schreibst es könne *sogenannte* Wortneuschöpfungen geben. Das schreibt man ja, um die Wortbedeutung anzuzweifeln wie in *sog. DDR*, 3. Du schreibst "Es gibt keinen Ursprung" um dann einen Ursprung darzustellen, nicht, dass es keinen logischen Ursprung gibt, was immer das sein soll. 4. Ist ein positiv klingendes Wort, das vor Gefahren warnen soll, nicht kontraproduktiv?

Comment: "gibt es bei zusammengesetzten Nomen keine richtigen Regeln. Zum Glueck, denn dadurch koennen sogenannte Wortneuschoepfungen entstehen" - ich sehe keinen zwingenden Grund, wieso Regeln für die Zusammensetzung von Nomen Wortneuschöpfungen verhindern sollten.

Comment: @userunknown: Zu 2.: *Sogenannt* wird aber durchaus auch bei der Einführung eines Begriffs in einem Text verwendet, auch wenn man den Begriff für vollkommen zutreffend hält. Vergleiche dazu beispielsweise das Verwendungsbeispiel ["feinste Blutgefäße, sogenannte Kapillaren"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sogenannt).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Dann schau mal Dein Beispiel und die Verwendung oben an. Bei den Kapillaren gibt es eine Erklären, was so genannt wird - hier nicht. Es ist einfach ein sinnloses Füllwort.

Comment: @userunknown: Bei der "Wortneuschöpfung" stellt eben schon das Wort selber die Erklärung dar, da sich die Bedeutung direkt aus den Wortbestandteilen ergibt. Das *sogenannt* bringt dabei zum Ausdruck, dass "Wortneuschöpfung" nicht einfach eine beliebige Umschreibung für das Phänomen ist, sondern der feste (bzw. zumindest für den vorliegenden Text definierte) Ausdruck dafür. Es ergibt also schon alles seinen Sinn.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Für mich ist eine sog. Wortneuschöpfung eine spöttische Negation, dass es wirklich eine ist, gerade weil an dem Wort nichts erklärungsbedürftig ist und weithin unbekannt ist es auch nicht. Du schreibst auch nicht eine *sogenannte Umschreibung für ein sogenanntes Phänomen*.

Comment: Aus der positiven Bewertung der Antwort schliesse ich, dass sie zumindest ein paar Leuten geholfen hat. Meiner Meinung nach muss man nicht ueber einen Ausdruck diskutieren den ich verwendet habe, nur weil eine Person sich daran stoert.